# Кавычки перед названием не по-русски написаного произведения

Tags: кавычки

При написании названий книг, не по-русски написанных, нужны кавычки?

`Мне нравится книжонка «Zahnräder und Federn des ältesten Wagens».`

`Мне нравится книжонка Zahnräder und Federn des ältesten Wagens.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я считаю, что кавычки нужны:

***Мне нравится книжонка «Zahnräder und Federn des ältesten Wagens»***.

Названия, написанные нерусским языком, в данном случае немецком, обычно не заключаются в кавычки, **но!** названия произведений, например литературных или музыкальных, даже написанных на другом языке, **заключаются в кавычки**. В данном случае название книги-произведения, поэтому, я считаю, кавычки нужны.

- «Грамота.ру»:

[image: ррсап прмрлип]